# how to set property value based on item and use that property as input of property function?

Tags: msbuild, .net, msbuild-4.0, msbuild-propertygroup

I am trying to set a property value based on Item 
But property doesn't seem to notice Item
For example, my code is like

```
<ItemGroup>
   <temp Include="test.txt"></temp>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <Name>%(temp.Identity)</Name>
  <Test>$([system.IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(Name)').Replace('ABC', '###'))</Test> 
</PropertyGroup>    

<Target Name="Write">
   <Message Text="$(Name)"/>
   <WriteLinesToFile File="%(temp.Filename).asl" Lines="$(Test)" Overwrite="true"/> 
</Target>
```

But when I run that, it says it cannot read %(temp.Identity)
Am I missing anything??
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are evaluated before any items. Move the group into a target for delayed evaluation, your "Write" or a generic [InitialTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcxfsh87.aspx) one.

See [Property and Item Evaluation Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/comparing-properties-and-items#property-and-item-evaluation-order).

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot about this!! Thank you!! :)